# How to handle GET request mounted with axios with specials caracters and accents

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, http, axios

Within the form of a web page built with **VUE.JS**, a GET request is mounted with **Axios**.

And depending on the value of some of the form's fields, may have special characters and accents.

For example, if in the surname form field, the user writes '**Ruíz**', the request is mounted like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/someController?surname=Ru%C3%ADz
```

It seems that '**í**' is converted to **%C3%AD**

This is what I have on Java side, in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public SignerQueryResponse getSignerList(
    @RequestParam(value = "surname", required = false) String surname,
    HttpServletRequest request) {

    //... all stuff

}
```

How can this be corrected?

Do I have to put something on the server side? .. in the Java Controller ??

... something related to **ISO-8859-1** encoding??

Thanks

Comment: You need to convert it by using `decodeURIComponent('Ru%C3%ADz')` on server.

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) should help

Comment: Thank you both for your comments

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, using **org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()**.

But I dont know if exists another more "cleaner", based on @annotations for example.

```
System.out.println(surname); //This gives me unproper: Ru&iacute;z
                
String unescapedSurname = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(surname);
System.out.println(unescapedSurname); //This gives me the proper: Ruíz
```